# Conference Call in php

Tags: php

I want to implement conference call facility in my website using PHP. Could you please suggest me the best way to implement.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a way, way too broad a subject to answer here. Anyway, you can't use PHP alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into twilio it provides this functionality in the form of a JavaScript code. The API is fairly simple to use and can very easily be done in PHP as they have fairly good documentation.

Comment: Hi Sean.. Why we cant use Goto Meeting Api.. Is there any main diference b/w Twillo and Goto Meeting

Comment: You can, but for me I have had more experience with the Twilio API over Goto Meeting's API.